# Elastic Beanstalk-Django: 500 deploy Internal Server Error

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My questions might similar to other stackoverflow's questions. I have tired every single questions' solutions but none of them did not work. I have created simple Django app and it works locally fine. My app structure like this: [image].

This my .ebextensions django.config.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: DjangoElasticbeanstalkdeploy/wsgi.py
```

**This is my requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.1.2
djangorestframework==3.12.1
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
```

I have used `default_platform: Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux`. My environment Heath looks good. Everything looks ok to me but when I click the url I am getting this error.

[image]

Comment: Can yoiu ssh into the instance, and `curl` your app from the inside to verify the ports and that it works as expected?

Comment: I did not use `ssh`

Comment: So do you know that your app is even working? If you connect from outside traffic is: EB->Nginx->your app. You need to verify that your app is working. Maybe just nginx expects different port?

Comment: I think my app path is wrong. Can you please check my app structure image.